# InvalidArgumentException error while trying to install CakePHP in WAMP

Tags: cakephp, windows-7, wamp

I am a beginner into **CakePHP**, I am trying to make a setup of **CakePHP** environment in my **Windows 7** PC. I could successfully install **composer**, but when i run this command(`composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app myapp`) to install **CakePHP v3.x**, I get an error `[InvalidArgumentException] Could not find package cakephp with stability stable.`

Here is the correct and right **Screenshot** of the error:
[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8tmf.png)

I am using WAMP server, and my PHP version is **5.3.8**

Please help me in fixing the issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Take a closer look at your screenshot, you did _not_ run the command that you are showing here in your question.

Comment: I have replaced the old screenshot with the correct one..

Answer (score 0):

I only means that you have not installed GIT yet, or forgot to set in PATH environment variable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But i don't understand what has GIT got to do with it.. Please have a look in to the **screenshot** attached in my question above, You see there my composer is working fine.

Comment: in the case the GIT is main actor. As you call your command

composer create-project cakephp/app

it tries to copy the 
https://github.com/cakephp/app

through GIT. it you can't execute git command from your command line, you will not be able to install it.

Comment: I installed GIT for windows and tried running the same command there but unfortunately the same error is popping in.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error I did upgrade Wampserver to 2.5 It's working fine.
because it has PHP 5.5.